# Pass % encoded in url using perl

Tags: perl, url, cgi, urlencode

I am trying to build a url using CGI input fields. One of the fields contain % as default value. Hence the url is being built as below:

```
$syscmd = "http://myserver:myport/reports/rwservlet?server=rptsvr+report=$REPORT";
$syscmd .= "+Xprocess=\"$in{'Xprocess'}\"";
```

The Xprocess variable contains % as default value and the url tunrs out to be something like below:

://myserver:myport/reports/rwservlet?server=rptsvr+report=apu_downtime_p+Xprocess=%

Now I am trying to traverse to that webpage and as % is not encoded to %25, I am facing with an error as shown below

**REP-52006: The specified URL %22%%22 cannot be decoded.**

Please help on how to encode % character in building the url.

Thank you.

Comment: You don't appear to *attempt* to [substitute](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators) the `%` with `%25`? (Or otherwise URI encode the value)

Answer (score 0):

You should use %25 for escaping %.

Here,

http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/

This can be useful in this case.

In your perl code, you could use URI::Encode (http://search.cpan.org/~mithun/URI-Encode-0.09/lib/URI/Encode.pm)